# Spring security form logging and outh2 in same app

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have written a sample spring application which have some rest services protected using `spring-security-oauth2`. Now I want to move these services to the original application which uses spring security form login.

In the original application I want rest services to be protected from `spring-security-oauth2` and other spring controllers to be protected using a form login. What I want to know is, is this approach is right or wrong, if right, how could I complete this action.

This is Sample app codes, which uses ouath2,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService; // Is this really needed?

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        // @formatter:off
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/test").not().permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/test").authenticated();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    @Autowired
    // @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore).authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients.inMemory().withClient("clientapp").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").authorities("USER")
                .scopes("read", "write").resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID).secret("123456");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
        return tokenServices;
    }

}

}
```

---

Here is a part of the original app configuration.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MyStaysureSecurityConfiguration extends      WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("mycompany").password("mypsswd").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/*", "/api-docs/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard").and().csrf().disable();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security is built on an ordered list of filter chains, and for each request the first one with a matching path handles the authentication. You have 3 filter chains in your combined app, one created by `@EnableAuthorizationServer` (with default order=0), one created by `@EnableResourceServer` (with default order=3), and one created by your `MyStaysureSecurityConfiguration` (also with order=0). You aren't allowed to have 2 filters with the same order so you need to re-arrange them and give them request matchers that make sense for your use case. Maybe you didn't need the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` anyway (it was unclear from the question)? In any case it is pretty simple - you have 2 choices (roughly):

1. exclude the oauth2 resources from the request matchers in your `MyStaysureSecurityConfiguration` and allow them to be handled by the resource server filter.
2. re-order the resource server filter to a lower order and give it a request matcher that only matches the oauth2 resources.