# How to configure multiple HttpSecurity with UserDetailsService using spring boot security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm working on with spring boot security layer to authenticate and authorize the user.Now, i would like to do some sample app using multi http security configuration.I have the scenario like there will be two login pages with different URL mappings("/managementLogin","/othersLogin").

I can understood how to configure multi httpsecurity configs but i need to validate the users from two tables.If the management users loggedIn i need to validate the user from management table through DAO layer using `UserDetailsService` else if any other users loggedIn i need to validate from other_users table.

Could anybody help me to know how to configure the multi http config and dao layer using `UserDetailsService` with spring boot security ?

Here is my basic code snippet,

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // for testing authentication purpose using inMemory db
        /*
         * auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles
         * ("USER").and().withUser("admin") .password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
         */

        // Dao based authentication
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        // CSRF tokens handling
        http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
          .antMatchers("/registerUser","/register.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }
}
```

TIA..,

Comment: If i understood correctly you don't want multiple userDetailsServices. Instead you want to implement loadByUsername in your userDetailsService to lookup for the given username in both tables aren't you? Or are some endpoints only allowed for users of one of these tables?

Comment: Why you need two distinct login endpoints?

Comment: @YannicKlem The reason two separate look-up tables might be required could be to avoid a potential login ID clash if its uniqueness across the two user types isn't guaranteed. Although a chance of accidental password match between the two tables for the same login ID is slim, the risk is always there.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom UserDetailsService like this:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private UserDaoTableOne userDaoTableOne;

  @Autowired
  private UserDaoTableTwo userDaoTableTwo;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    UserDetails user = userDaoTableOne.find(username);

    if(user == null){
        user = userDaoTableTwo.find(username);
    }

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Username '%s' not found", username));
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: What if, both tables had same user?

Comment: mhh .. valid objection.. but i would see that as an edgecase which have to be handled in an individual way. I would expect usernames to only appear once. Even in different tables. If thats not the case, handle this in the loadByUsername method. My implementation is just a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

Implement two DaoAuthenticationProvider with his own UserDetailsService and inject both providers to the authenticationManager.

I don't know what is the requisite for two distinct login endpoints but at first I think is a bad idea.
You can create different [Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) objects an let the AuthenticationManager choose the correct AuthenticationProvider based in the supports method.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you will need to use, two user detail services. But, that wont be enough. I suggest you to create another `ApplicationSecurity2` class with different order.

> Spring security is built on an ordered list of filter chains.

see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893602/spring-security-form-logging-and-outh2-in-same-app) given here by [Dave Sayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259109/dave-syer). Then you can handle different urls, as you want.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I checked into two repositories, Below an exemple that I use:

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        AbstractUser user;
        try {
            user = clientRepository.findByUsername(username);
        }
        catch (Exception userException) {
            try {
                user = adminRepository.findByUsername(username);
            }
            catch (Exception adminException) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user present with username : " + username);
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: What if two different users has same username in both client and admin table?

Answer (score 0):

I have to handle around same issue , i have autowired httprequest class in userdetail service and get request params type and drive my logic based on that.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly solve the issue as the recommended solutions, but you can create a simple trick  to define two different `UserDetailsService` as here I have two user one as a normal user and another as an editor  :

editor

```
@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class EditorService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final EditorRepository editorRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if(username == null || "".equals(username)){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("null value");
        }

        Optional<Editor> editor = editorRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if(editor.isPresent()){
            log.info("created under editor service: " + editor.get());
            return editor.get();
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("does not exists");
    }

}
```

user

```
@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if(username == null || "".equals(username)){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("null");
        }

        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if(user.isPresent()){
            log.info("cretaed under User service : " + user.get());
            return user.get();
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("does not exists");
    }
}
```

then on the configurations side, we can use of spring order mechanism :

user config :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order(1)
public class UserWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserService userService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/user/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Editor config :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EditorWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final EditorService editorService;
    @Lazy
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http // all other requests handled here
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.editorService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```